# "from osgeo import gdal" error not working on ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: python, pip, conda, gdal

I installed gdal from pip as well as conda forge that is completed. but when I import it pushes an error. Can anyone guides me the way forward.

```
python -c "from osgeo import gdal"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hmahmad/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/hmahmad/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/hmahmad/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/hmahmad/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

System specs:

1. ubuntu 18.04.5
2. python 3.8.5
   and when I install it again it says

```
pip install GDAL
Requirement already satisfied: GDAL in /home/hmahmad/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.3.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by installing [Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library with conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge rasterio
```

I dont know whats the connection behind but it seems like it installed all the relevant dependant libraries and it make gdal work.

Comment: BURN THIS WIZARD!! Your'e a genius! After spend days reading THOUSAND posts you gave me the perfect solution. Seems ```conda install -c conda-forge <ANYTHING>``` will make all libs installed via APT to be connected to Jupyter environment.

Comment: Thanks @magna. The same happened to me when I had this problem. took me a couple of days to end up with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing `libiconv.so.2` shared library. You should install libiconv manually.
[Installing libiconv on Ubuntu Linux](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/libiconv/installation/installing_libiconv_on_ubuntu_linux.php)

Comment: not working. now this error is arrising `ImportError: /home/hmahmad/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/../../../libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: _ZNK6libdap5Error17get_error_messageB5cxx11Ev`